# Understanding Scala Do Later Pattern

Tags: scala

In a Scala codebase I see this:

```
override def borrow(implicit doLater: DoLater): Borrow = {
  ...

  doLater({
    store.shutdown(10.seconds)
    close()
  })
  ...
```

The above code gets called like this:

```
val d = new DoLater
    try {
      f(d)
```

and `f` is a function that looks like this:

```
implicit doLater =>
      val borrows = borrow
```

What is going on in above `doLater({...` call? Is it going to call the apply method and pass in this bracketed thing? `doLater` in the `borrow` method is an instance of the `DoLater` class right? What is the bracketed thing? Is it an anonymous class?

the `doLater` is an instance of this class:

```
class DoLater {
    var thingsToDo: Seq[() => Unit] = Seq.empty
    override def apply(d: => Unit) = {
      thingsToDo = d _ +: thingsToDo
    }
    ...
```

I'm just trying to figure out, Scala-Wise... what is going on in the `doLater({...` call. Why does it work? Is the apply method being called? Is it a constructor?

Comment: That seems too broad and quite unclear. There are thousand undefined entities flying around. Scala's codebase isn't exactly small. Should we now all go and search for this piece of code? Is it even in any way more important than any other piece of code?

Comment: My main question is at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You could tell it's an `apply` method being called because you already have an instance of that class passed via implicit parameter: `(implicit doLater: DoLater)`. The only way something can be called as a function with `(...)` is if it's a function/method or some sort of object that has an apply method. In fact, functions are objects with `apply` methods themselves. For example see [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/scala/Function1.html). That's how we know it's an apply.

This method takes any value passed by name aka lazily evaluated: `apply(d: => Unit)` and it will just add it to a list of things to do later. Judging by the signature: `thingsToDo: Seq[() => Unit]` it's a (todo) list of side effecting functions.

When `doLater` is being invoked with `doLater({ ...})` you are effectively passing a code block that is not evaluated at the moment, because the parameter pass is by name, not by value as we already know.

Comment: If it's an instance of thay class, why do you know the apply method is being called?

Comment: Is the lambda or function by name syntax shorthand for a parameterless function?

Comment: You can read up more on by name param passing here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html. Whatever you pass as a parameter should produce or be a value of the type `T` in `(x: => T)`. It might be another lazy value or a parameterless function that produces `T` - Scala will treat them the same.

Comment: Is the curly brackets that are passed in this example a parameterless function shorthand?

Comment: No, curly braces are a code block which has represents some value - the value and type of the last statement. You treat it as a function here, because you create that block but don't evaluate it - sounds a lot like a function. The only reason it's not evaluated immediately is that it's passed lazily/by name to another function. Same works with `lazy val = {...}`. Afterwards, you convert it to an anonymous function by adding underscore - this will prevent it from being evaluated before being added to the `thingsToDo`.

Comment: A subtle difference here is that your function takes `T` lazily, not `() => T`. You use `_` to do that conversion to be able to store it as a parameterless function.

Comment: So you're telling me the paramter of the object that it is passed to makes it so that the code block isn't evaluated immedlately? Sorry would you mind passing in a more fleshed out example in your answer because it really sounds like you know what you're talking about and it'd really help me but I'm a bit unclear on the details still. Any idea where in the Odersky book this is all written?

Comment: How does the code block represent both value and type?

Comment: You need to break it down into digestible pieces to understand: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html, See `blocks` and `functions` in https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/basics.html, See `Unit` in https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html, implicit param: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html. The best way to get clear answers on SO is to ask a smaller well defined questions ;). If you read Odersky's book you'll definitely understand all of it. Try by name func in REPL and see what you can pass to it: `def calculate(input: => Int) = input * 37`.